# Declaring object of arrays in Typescript; getting error Type '{}' missing the following properties

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
  const qn = props.question.question // == question number
  const statusLib: { [index: number]: {} } = {
    82: ["70%", "0%", "0%", 1, 1],
    83: ["70%", "0%", "0%", 1, 2],
    84: ["100%", "45%", "0%", 2, 3],
    85: ["100%", "70%", "0%", 2, 3],
    86: ["100%", "100%", "46%", 3, 3],
  }
  const s:Array<ReactText> = statusLib[qn] // squiggly under 's'. Should return array
```

I want to keep it short and sweet. This should be min reproducible example. I tried various permutations, with about the same result.

I never had a problem rendering on local server. It's strictly a typescript enforcement thing.

`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2740)`

I'm still learning the semantics of TS but my understanding is from this
  `const statusLib: { [index: number]: {} } = {`

you're declaring how the the object should be indexed, and then that it is an object of the most general type.

My assignment `s = ...` obviously returns an array. If I wasn't my code wouldn't work at all. Typescript thinks it's an object, so maybe I'm accidentally telling it that. I tried various ways to tell it all the contents are arrays such as :

`const statusLib: { [index: number]: {[]} } = {`
and
 `s:any[]`

StatusLib is an object indeed but it's children are all arrays. How do I tell TS this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array like `["70%", "0%", "0%", 1, 1]` that you typehint as an empty object `{}`. You at least need an array `[]`, which could be `any[]` (worst), `unknown[]` (still bad), `(string|number)[]` (getting close), yet since your array is consistent it seems to be a tuple that you could type in the form of:

```
type MyTuple = [string, string, string, number, number];
```

Then your typing should become

```
 const statusLib: { [index: number]: MyTuple }
```

(You don't need the custom type defintion. It may be useful in the long run.)

Comment: Thanks. I got it working-- see my comment above. I inlined it and it works. ```const statusLib: { [index: number]: [string, string, string, number, number] } = {...```

Answer (score 1):

You are telling TS that your statusLib is an object `{}` with key value pairs of type `number: object` but then you actually need them as `number: array` this the error that it expects object `index: {}` but instead its getting `index: []`. Try the following

```
const statusLib: { [index: number]: Array<string | number> }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier but I got an error on the numbers and I just gave up on that approach too quickly. I should have looked at the error:  "Type [string string string number number] is not assignable to [ ]. I changed [] to [string, string, string, number, number] and it works, builds and deploys

Comment: It can be changed to (string | number) [] or even better Array<string | number> check this https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-array